# Creating a blank table by merging/concatenating two table names

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, mysqli

I want to create a table by merging two table names.

**Example**

**Table 1 - user**

**Table 2 - Name**

So, I have to create a table **userName**

How do I achieve this result?

SQL QUERY : CREATE TABLE ?

I'm using **php** and `mysqli_query()`to execute the query. How can I concatenate the two table names to create a new one in mysql?

Table names are in `$table1` and `$table2`?

Connection - `$conn`

How do I specify the schema of the table? 
Query:`CREATE TABLE ? (schema)`;
I want to replace ? with the table name obtained by merging two table names. ie userName

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this:

```
$sql = "CREATE TABLE " .  $table1 . $table2  . " (ID INT NOT NULL)";
```

Or something like this:

```
CREATE TABLE userName SELECT * FROM user, name;
```

You can create one table from another by adding a SELECT statement at the end of the CREATE TABLE statement:

```
CREATE TABLE new_tbl [AS] SELECT * FROM orig_tbl;

mysql> SELECT * FROM foo;
+---+
| n |
+---+
| 1 |
+---+

mysql> CREATE TABLE bar (m INT) SELECT n FROM foo;
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.02 sec)
Records: 1  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql> SELECT * FROM bar;
+------+---+
| m    | n |
+------+---+
| NULL | 1 |
+------+---+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

For each row in table foo, a row is inserted in bar with the values from foo and default values for the new columns.

You can read more about this in:

> https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-table-select.html

Comment: I want to create a table with the table name concatenated by two table names i.e user and name. I want to creata a blank table `userName` without any data inside it ? How do I specify the schema? I don't want to create any data inside. The query result should create a table userName.

Comment: @psychoCoder ok, wait a minute

Comment: @psychoCoder and why you don't make CREATE TABLE $table1 . $table2

Comment: So I can write this CREATE TABLE $table1.$table2 ( ID INT NOT NULL); Will it work?

Comment: @psychoCoder I edit my answer, see it and tell if you solved your problem

Comment: It did. Problem Solved. A new doubt though : If I don't use `""` here. Query : CREATE TABLE $table1.$table2 .. My query will be decoded to CREATE TABLE user.name Right?? Because it's not working if I'm using it this way

Comment: @psychoCoder $sql = "CREATE TABLE " .  $table1 . "." . $table2;